Windows 10 WSL icon replaced by a weird one
I don't know how to describe it, it is a weird one.
I think it had some errors while updating WSL so I modified the registry a little bit but I have some difficulty find that post now. It didn't directly cause this weird issue till recently.


Did you created registry backup, if yes you can revert back to the registry before by going to "Files" and then import and choosing the backup.
If you dont have backup (which's appearently the case), look for the changes by date modified. Right click on the registry's column, there you will find "more" option, and select "Date modified" There you can enter the date you made changes to get the changes you made. Find out that specific post and revert it from there.
